# VueJS List Transitions JavaScript Hooks aren't being called for every element in list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a grid of divs in rows and columns and a transition group as follows:

```html
<div class="row" v-for="row in grid">
    <div class="col-md-3" v-for="col in row">
        <transition-group 
                    v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter"
                    v-on:enter="enter"
                    v-on:after-enter="afterEnter"
                    v-on:leave="leave"
                    v-bind:css="false">
            <div class="box" :key="col">{{col}}</div>
        </transition-group>
    </div>
</div>
```

The grid changes completely when a button is clicked (not shown in above html). The transitions are supposed to scale down the removed **.box** divs and then scale up the newly added **.box** divs.

It seems to be working fine. However, for some reason, some **.box** divs are not being animated at all (scale up or down) and they will just disappear (when removed) or appear at 100% size (when added).

Take a look at this gif to know what I mean:

[image]

I am assuming Vue is reusing these DOM elements so its not applying the transition methods on them?!

Here are the transition methods:

```js
beforeEnter: function (el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
},
enter: function (el, done) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        el.style.display = 'block';
        $(el).velocity({
            scale: [1, 0.1],
        }, {
            duration: 2400,
            complete: done
        });
    }, 2400);
},
afterEnter: function (el) {},
leave: function (el, done) {
    $(el).velocity({
        scale: [0.1, 1],
    }, {
        duration: 2400,
        complete: done
    });
},
```

I have created a pen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WajaOE with the demo shown in the above gif.

**(NOTE: The demo generates random data so if things appear to work fine, try refresh to get a bigger grid in one of the sections).**

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a similar issue.

Comment: @MSC Unfortunately no, but it looks like as expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-3" v-for="col in row">
 <transition-group >
 </transition-group>
</div>
```

> I am assuming Vue is reusing these DOM elements

Yes, But the problem is:
When **leave-cols** count less then **enter-cols**, is means there are not enough  **transitionGroup Component**, so some **.box** divs can not emit **enter event** just like first load.